# I created a python script for my Firebase Cloud Messaging service, now how should I host this?

Tags: python, firebase-cloud-messaging

I created a python script to handle my Firebase Cloud Messaging service. What would be the best course of action in terms of trying to host it?

Extra Info:
I've tested that it works but I need it to be running constantly, and not on my own PC.

Answer (score 1):

Following are the options when it comes to hosting API's or functions.

- Heroku:
  Heroku is a cloud platform that lets companies build, deliver, monitor and scale apps.[How to host python scripts on heorku](https://github.com/michaelkryukov/heroku-python-script)
- AWS App Runner: AWS App Runner is a fully managed service that makes it easy for developers to quickly deploy containerized web applications and APIs.[How to deploy python script on AWS App Runner](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/deploy-python-application-using-aws-app-runner/)

Answer (score 1):

try aws lambda
you can choose to use it with api gateway or run it as a cronjob or what ever options you need